# VueJS transition on element in a loop?

Tags: vue.js, transition

This is my code: I want to create a transition on the HelloWorld Component, everytime the data gets updated. The transition itself works fine

```
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="awesome">Vue is awesome</p>
  </transition>
```

Here are my "cards" which are created dynamically.

```
  <v-row no-gutters>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="4" md="4" v-for="(todo, index) in todos" v-bind:key="index">
      <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
        <transition name="fade">
          <HelloWorld
            v-bind:todos="todos"
            v-bind:index="index"
            v-bind:class="(todos[index].done)?'green':'red'"
          />
        </transition>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
```

Here the transition does not work.

CSS is here:

```
<style scoped>
.top {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid black;
}

.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.fade-leave {
}

.fade-leave-active {
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Why and how do it get it done to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to animate `each` element in a loop, you have to:

- Put `transition` around the loop.
- And also, use `<transition-group>`, not just `<transition>`

```
<v-row no-gutters>
  <transition-group name="fade-in" mode="out-in">
    <v-col cols="12" sm="4" md="4" v-for="(todo, index) in todos" v-bind:key="index">
      <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
        <HelloWorld
          v-bind:todos="todos"
          v-bind:index="index"
          v-bind:class="(todos[index].done)?'green':'red'"
        />
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </transition-group>
</v-row>
```

And I would also advise you not to use `1s` long animation, it's way too long. Do something like this:

### CSS

```
.fade-in-enter-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.fade-in-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.fade-in-enter, .fade-in-leave-to {
  position: absolute; /* add for smooth transition between elements */
  opacity: 0;
}
```

If the animation is twitchy, you can add `position: absolute;` in the `enter` and `leave-to` CSS rules (or only for `leave-active`).

Check out this page in vue docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions

Comment: thank you, transition works, but it cracks up the width of my cards totally :-/

Comment: @DataMastery glad I could help. I updated the question (at the bottom) try it out.

Comment: @DataMastery you can also try putting `position: absolute;` only inside the `.fade-in-leave-active` class instead of the other two, this might change the way it looks since it will only be `absolute` during the transition, you can see it demonstrated on the provided vue docs page

Comment: Just a note for anyone else coming across this, I needed to change the "name" attribute to "fade-in" when using this example.

Answer (score 1):

```
<v-row no-gutters>
  <transition-group name="fade" class="row">
    <v-col cols="12" sm="4" md="4" v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="todo.randomKey">
      <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
        <HelloWorld
          v-bind:todos="todos"
          v-bind:index="index"
          v-bind:class="(todos[index].done)?'green':'red'"
        />
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
   </transition-group>
 </v-row>
```

you need to do multiple edits:

1. use `<transition-group>` instead of `<transition>`.
2. wrap `<v-col>` using `<transitiono-group>`.
3. add `class="row"` to the `<transition-group>`.
4. replace the `index` with a unique key inside todo objects for
   example `todo.id` or `todo.randomKey`. Using `index` as key is like
   not using a key at all.